# Maximal domain of an unbounded linear operator in a weighted Hilbert-space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, operator-theory, differential-operators, unbounded-operators

Let's consider the following (unbounded) linear operator. (So called transport operator in some context.)
$$ \mathrm{T}: \mathcal{H} \supset \mathcal{D}(\mathrm{T}) \to \mathcal{H} , f \mapsto \mathrm{T}f:= v \cdot \partial_xf(x,v), $$ where $\mathcal{H}$ is a weighted Hilbert space defined by
$ \mathcal{H} := L^2(\mathbb{T}^1 \times \mathbb{R}, M(v)^{-1}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}v)$, $ M(v) := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{1}{2}v^2},$ and the dot product on $\mathcal{H}$ is defined by
$$ (f,g)_{\mathcal{H}} := \int_{\mathbb{T}^1 \times \mathbb{R}}\frac{f(x,v)g(x,v)}{M(v)} \, \, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}v,$$ $\mathbb{T}^1$ denotes the one-dimensional torus.

It is easy to verify that $\mathrm{T}$ is formally a skew-symmetric operator w.r.t. $(\cdot, \cdot)_{\mathcal{H}}$.

$\mathcal{D}(\mathrm{T})$ denotes the maximal domain of $\mathrm{T}$ which should be unique, dense and $\mathrm{T}$ should be a closed operator on $\mathcal{D}(\mathrm{T})$. $\mathcal{R}(\mathrm{T})$ denotes the range of $\mathrm{T}.$
My question is now how can I define and determine $\mathcal{D}(\mathrm{T})$ and how can I easily describe/characterize $\mathcal{D}(\mathrm{T})$ explicitly? The same question for $\mathcal{R}(\mathrm{T})$.
The derivative $\partial_x$ is to be understood in the weak-sense, so for all $v \in \mathbb{R}$ we will need $f(x,v) \in H^1(\mathbb{T}^1)$ (Sobolev-space) for example.
My conjecture would be
$$ \mathcal{D}(\mathrm{T}) = \left \{f \in \mathcal{H} : \int_{\mathbb{T}^1 \times \mathbb{R}} \frac{v^2(\partial_xf(x,v))^2}{M(v)}\, \, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}v < + \infty \right\} = \{f \in \mathcal{H} : \mathrm{T}f \in  \mathcal{H} \},$$ so that $(\mathrm{T}f, g)_{\mathcal{H}}$ for arbitrary $g \in \mathcal{H}$ is at least well-defined.

Would be grateful for any help and ideas!

Comment: "Maximal domain" is not a precise well defined term, rather it's usually done in the other order: one first defines an operator that feels maximal in an intuitive sense and then calls this "maximal". Typical example: $d/dx$ on $L^2(0,1)$, maximal domain $H^1$.

Comment: I am not sure if I got your idea correctly. I was just wondering if my  conjecture is correct with the choose of $\mathcal{D}(\mathrm{T})$ ? The density follows because $ C_c^{\infty}(\mathrm{T}^1 \times \mathbb{R})$ is dense in $\mathcal{H}$ and $  C_c^{\infty}(\mathrm{T}^1 \times \mathbb{R}) \subseteq \mathcal{D}(\mathrm{T}).$